# Update Int32 in Task c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, task

is there any way to increment a value of an int inside a task? 
or is this a correct syntax in incrementing an int in task?
sample code:

```
public int erCount = 9;
static void Main(string[] args){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
        ...do some task
        if(errorfound)
            erCount++;
    });
    Task.Wait();
    Console.Writeline(erCount.toString());
}
```

I seem not to get it in incrementing value inside a thread. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: You are displaying the error line before the Task has probably even started... But other than that, `Interlocked.Increment` is your friend if you want to update an `int` from a background thread.

Comment: You can use [Interlocked.Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Here's a good read on how to synchronize tasks: http://prasadhonrao.com/how-to-avoid-race-condition-in-csharp/

Comment: is Interlocked.Increment usable in .net 4.0?

Comment: @Reyn: Yes it is. Add `using System.Threading;` to the top of your file.

Comment: You've added `Task.Wait()` to your code, does that means you're already doing it? If so, post a code which will compile and reproduce the problem. At the moment your code won't compile.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, ive changed it but it was back at the time when I received no answers yet. 

Also, thank you for giving me a clear answer to my problem, Upped up your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is fine as long as you're not modifying the `erCount` in multiple threads. In which case you'd need a lock or `Interlocked.Increment`.

Your problem is you're not waiting for the started `Task` to complete.

```
public static int erCount = 9;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
        ...do some task
        if(errorfound)
            Interlocked.Increment(ref erCount);
    });
    task.Wait();//Wait for the task to complete
    Console.Writeline(erCount.toString());
}
```

You may altogether remove the shared field and return the error count. That way you can avoid unnecessary synchronization.

```
public static int erCount = 9;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
        int localErrorCount =0;
        ...do some task
        if(errorfound)
            localErrorCount++;
       return localErrorCount;
    });
    int errors = task.Result;//Wait for the task to complete and get the error count
    erCount += errors;
    Console.Writeline(erCount.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! saved me a lot of headaches. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Interlocked.Increment()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public int erCount = 9;
static void Main(string[] args){
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{ 
        ...do some task
        if(errorfound)
            Interlocked.Increment(ref erCount);
    });

    task.Wait(); // Wait for the task to complete before showing the error count
    Console.Writeline(erCount.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not incrementing is:

```
Console.Writeline(erCount.toString());
```

executes before the error count has been incremented.

Move that inside the task at the end, and it should work.

You probably need to have a read up on the Task parrallel library and how multithreading works.